# Starting a project with Spring 3

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, spring-mvc, spring-3

At work we have a (large... 1-2 years of development ahead with a dozen of people in the team) project that will soon start and the "higher ups" are considering Spring 3 as the web framework (marketing hot air... whatever).

This is not a trivial web application and we don't have experience with Spring 3 (although we have some experience with Spring 2 already... but we're by no means experts). We are supposed to learn Spring 3 and start coding.

But there is this feeling I have that we'll have a hard time.

Spring 3 GA is around for an year or so and books seem not to have yet catched up. There is Pro Spring 3 and the third edition of Spring in action that I found so far covering Spring 3. The online tutorials are not very complex, and it seems the reference is all we've got as a solid foundation (which is a terse document).

As I said, I have a bad feeling. Don't get me wrong I don't mind learning Spring 3 (easy or hard going) but I'm not sure about the "safety of the project" (large project, small time frame... smell of death march) if we go with Spring 3.

I'm making an appeal to your experience. Have you created large projects with Spring 3? What issues did you encounter?

Comment: Honestly if you already know Spring from version 2, you know how to use Spring, period. 3.0 adds a few new modules and options, but it's not drastically different, and doesn't take things away. The core of the DI concept is still the same.

Answer (score 7):

Spring 3 is not million light years away from Spring 2 / 2.5. If you have quite some experience with spring and spring MVC, then go for it.

But bear in mind that spring MVC is not the *best* web framework out there. It just takes the same old concepts a bit further ahead.

If you want something that was done with the idea of websites in mind, try Scala Lift, JRuby + Rails or PlayFramework. I'm not saying that you should code everything in scala or Ruby, but check if those frameworks give you an edge on the web part, and use any Java technology (such as spring IOC) to build your logic.

Also, if the *Architects* of that application want security over potential fast delivery, Spring 3 is a good choice.

One of the downsides of SpringMVC (used with JSP or JSTL) is that is not really component based framework, so it's not ideal for complex, rich clients.

As a side note, I'm using spring 3 + MVC on a small web site with quite a lot of backend processing and I'm very happy with it.

Comment: Have you developed a site with Lift or Play?   Just curious, since they are both very new.

Comment: no, I haven't. I have some friends who are using Lift (and I forgot about Clojure!) and they totally rave about it. I wanted to use PlayFramework on my current project, but my client has/is training a lot of devs with Spring technologies, so they preferred  to use Spring. Given that the app is mostly backend processing, it doesn't really matter as there are few pages and no ajax.

Comment: Scala is too hard to use. google "scala is hard" and you would find the answer

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to you to check out Spring Roo: 
http://www.springsource.org/roo
and STS:
http://www.springsource.com/products/springsource-tool-suite-download

With these tools you are able to generate an app within 10minutes, literally, with database access layer with rich domain objects reverse engineered from your database, authorization & authentication (Spring Security), web UI layer (different options), logging. It will probably not suit your needs but it's an excellent option to actually see how a Spring 3 app 'should' look like. (In STS there is a refactor option called 'push-in' refactor which enables you to get rid of Roo once your skeleton is generated)

Also a great source of information is the YouTube channel of SpringSource: http://www.youtube.com/user/SpringSourceDev

Spring is a great family of frameworks, but you should keep in mind that it's not very easy to do things right with it and by using it the wrong way you *can* get yourself in trouble.
Generally I would absolutely recommend Spring, but if your timeframe doesn't allow you to spend some time learning the details, you should probably stick to your known technology stack.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Spring 3 in my projects. It is conceptually not very different from 2/2.5, at the same time adds lot of shortcuts for achieving the same goodness with less xml (and code).

The thing that i don't like about Spring is the class names/interfaces/packages look like an essay to me : `org.springframework.somemodule.somethingmorespecififc.FooSomethingWithBlahContextInBar`

Also if you are not using Maven and try to include jar manually, you are doomed. However, large projects should use maven :)

That said, Spring Ioc is excellent choice for any size of application. I am not a huge fan of Spring MVC though and never really used it in project so far. But most java web framework suck.

With spring, application configuration is breeze, like setting up DataSource (connection pool), EntityManager etc. Integration with various frameworks is also much easier like Struts2, Hibernate (JPA), Velocity/Freemarker. LDAP (and Active Directory) via Spring LDAP is awesome, (we are using it).

and Finally Spring security itself can be the sole reason to use Spring in a large project.

You can give a shot to spring 3 using [appfuse](http://appfuse.org/) in almost no time.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your definition of "large project" is. That said, I've been using Spring for years; Spring 3 is the first major revision that *really* kickstarted Spring as an easy-to-use framework that I was happy to have any sort of dependency on.

Spring 2.5 was a leap in the right direction, but Spring 3 is a major improvement. Spring MVC is all right; it's not fantastic IMO but it's serviceable.

But as far as Spring 3 itself is concerned, I'd not have any qualms whatsoever with using it as a technology platform, although you should consider whether you trust SpringSource/VMWare. (That said, I don't have any reason to say NOT to trust SpringSource, although their understandings of OSGi and cloud computing are... odd.)

Spring will have no negative impact on the life of the project, and writing code for use in Spring tends to make the code of higher quality because leveraging injection frameworks tends to yield easier testing.

Comment: Fair enough, but that's not a very large project. Spring will only help you. :)